# Can we stop Windows 8 phone showing mobile site?

Tags: mobile, windows-8

As a publishing website required authentication when viewed on a mobile device, we've updated `compat.browser` on our server to allow Android, iPhone and Windows 7 phones to view the full version of our public facing website, rather than the automatic mobile version.

However, my boss just got a new Windows 8 mobile phone (make/model unknown at this point) and it's showing the mobile version of the site. Looking at `compat.browser`, I don't see an entry for WindowsPhone8, which is expected as it's fairly new, in comparison with SharePoint 2010, at least.

Does anyone know what codes I can add to `compat.browser` to ensure all Windows 8 phones see the full site? (I saw full, as a colleague has windows a Windows 8 phone and DOES see the full site)?

I'm guessing I can add something like

```
<browser id="WindowsPhone7Up" parentID="IE6to9">
```

but for WindowsPhone8?

Cheers

Kevin

Comment: Turns out what actually happening is that when my colleague clicks a emailed link to our website using his phone, Office Hub is automatically detecting our site as a SharePoint site and opens it in a SharePoint app within Office Hub. From what we can tell, no browser is being launched at all. When the same URL from the email is copied into the browser, the page looks just fine. We did find that you can configure Office Hub to not do this, but we can't expect customers to know this. I need to find a way to tell Office Hub that our site is not SharePoint, or disable this feature somehow.